# Sitecore Rocks fails when creating new rendering

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I have installed Sitecore Rocks 2.0 and it seems not working with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I have established connection and when going to create rendering from my Visual Studio solution it's throwing below error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Rocks, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a3d60f56f7d71b90' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the `Sitecore.Rocks.Server.dll` in the bin folder of the instance you are connecting and also `Sitecore.Rocks.Validation.ashx` in the `Website\sitecore\shell\WebService`?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya yeah we have handler in above location and also have only one "Sitecore.Rocks.Server.dll" assembly related to rocks.
but assembly version is 2.0.0.40 but in above error it's trying to find version 1.0.0.0.

Comment: Have you tried uninstall it and re-install the Sitecore Rocks? You may check the following link: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/installing-sitecore-rocks-with-visual-studio-2013-john-west-sitecore-blog

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I have tested on different machines as well.
version mentioned in john's blog is 1.2 with vs2013 which is working fine but I guess issue is with latest version 2.0
might be some dependencies missing or what ?
We installed latest because sitecore latest release of 8.2 does not support old rocks version.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore Rocks have deprecated support for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. Currently, the minimum version Sitecore Rocks integrates with is Visual Studio 2015.

> Sitecore Rocks no longer supports Visual Studio 2013 as Microsoft has
>   not made the Visual Studio 2013 SDK available on NuGet.

Sitecore Rocks integrates directly with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and 2017.